# Why can not I get any row in a MySQL query from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, mysql

The problem I have is that I can not visualize any row with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY ([LINK_MYSQL], 'SELECT * FROM mysql.vw_bd_date;')
```

The query did not show any error except that it did not throw me any lines either. The consulted view found in MySQL is the following:

```
create view vw_bd_date
as
SELECT `information_schema`.`TABLES`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` AS `base_de_datos`,MIN(`information_schema`.`TABLES`.`CREATE_TIME`) AS `FECHA_CREACION` 
FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` 
WHERE ((`information_schema`.`TABLES`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` NOT IN ('information_schema','sys','mysql','performance_schema','test','test\\_%')) 
AND (`information_schema`.`TABLES`.`DATA_LENGTH` IS NOT NULL) AND (`information_schema`.`TABLES`.`INDEX_LENGTH` IS NOT NULL)) 
GROUP BY `information_schema`.`TABLES`.`TABLE_SCHEMA`
```

This is the use in a much larger query where I do the `join` with other views to perform a database inventory, but also as commented, the fields in this particular view throw me `NULL`.

We tried to do all kinds of `cast` without success.

Any idea would be very helpful.

Thank you

Comment: The default schema in MySQL is `mysql`?  I'm not a MySQL DBA, but figured I'd ask since it's not specified in the view definition.

Comment: The view is created in the database `mysql`, but as you can see, said view queries the information_schema.

Comment: Could it be that the NULLs come from partitioned tables?

Comment: @JohnEisbrener - MySQL does not have a `.dbo.`.  The syntax is `dbname.tablename.colname` (with suitable defaults in some cases).  So `information_schema` is the "database name" aka "schema" in MySQL terminology.

Comment: As for `FROM mysql.vw_bd_date` -- You should _not_ declare anything (eg, this `VIEW`) in the `mysql` database.

Comment: The `null` is because the columns of the other views do throw data while the mentioned view does not, then SQL Server completes them with` null`. When I consult only at view it does not show any line as expected.

Comment: What results are you expecting to see, and do you see them when querying directly in MySQL?

Comment: The result of the query is a list of database with its creation dates, and it can be visualized if one does it directly in the MySQL database, the problem is when I use `openquery` in SQL Server, it does not throw me rows, just the header of the columns.

Comment: Are you using the same user to connect to MySQL and run the query as you're using in the Linked Server definition?

Comment: Yes, it is set with the root user, as I mentioned in a previous comment, this view is part of a larger query, I realized that I had problems because it did not bring any value and the fields were autocompleted with `null` values. It would be good if one of you replicates that scenario to see if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm obviously not even close to proficient in MySQL, my answer won't really focus on that side of your question.  If the view returns what you are expecting from within MySQL, I suspect the issue is on the SQL Server side.  What driver are you using?  If it's the built-in Microsoft driver for MySQL, I would strongly recommend downloading the [MySQL Driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) from their site and installing that as a new provider on your SQL Server.  When connecting to other RDBMS systems, I have had significantly better luck using the driver provided by the vendor of that application rather than using the generic driver provided by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using openquery requires using UPPERCASE for the object names and field names for the remote database.

This does not work for me:

```
select * From openquery(kace,' select *  FROM hd_ticket 
        where ID in (93,105,124,146,148) ')
```

While this query does:

```
select * From openquery(kace,' select *  FROM HD_TICKET 
        where ID in (93,105,124,146,148) ')
```